# Apple Accelerate framework produce cepstrum unexpected results

Tags: frameworks, signal-processing, fft

I'm following [an article](http://iitg.vlab.co.in/?sub=59&brch=164&sim=615&cnt=1) on how to produce a cepstrum for use in detecting speech formants and coding it using the iPhone Accelerate framework. However, the results are not quite as the article expects. For unvoiced sections (figure 3 in the article) it shows smaller values in the first few bins. However, when my code runs, the unvoiced sections have large values (towards 1.0) which looks more like a voiced section.

Here is my code:

```
// copy buffer data into a separate array and apply hamming window
// don't use leadlength because we copied to beginning of buffer
int offset = (int)(s * stepSize);
float *hamBuffer = malloc(n*sizeof(float));
for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    hamBuffer[i] = hpBuffer[offset+i] * ((1.0f-0.46f) - 0.46f*cos(TWOPI*i/((float)n-1.0f)));

// configure float array into acceptable input array format (interleaved)
vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX*)hamBuffer, 2, &complexArray, 1, halfN);

// free ham buffer
free(hamBuffer);

// run FFT
vDSP_fft_zrip(setupReal, &complexArray, stride, log2n, FFT_FORWARD);

// Absolute square (equivalent to mag^2)
complexArray.imagp[0] = 0.0f;
vDSP_zvmags(&complexArray, 1, complexArray.realp, 1, halfN);
bzero(complexArray.imagp, (halfN) * sizeof(float));

// scale
float scale = 1.0f / (2.0f*(float)n);
vDSP_vsmul(complexArray.realp, 1, &scale, complexArray.realp, 1, halfN);

// get log of absolute values for passing to inverse FFT for cepstrum
float *logmag = malloc(sizeof(float)*halfN);
for (int i=0; i < halfN; i++)
    logmag[i] = log10f(fabsf(complexArray.realp[i]));

// configure float array into acceptable input array format (interleaved)
vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX*)logmag, 2, &complexArray, 1, halfN/2);

// create cepstrum
vDSP_fft_zrip(setupReal, &complexArray, stride, log2n-1, FFT_INVERSE);

// scale again
scale = (float) 1.0 / (2 * n);
vDSP_vsmul(complexArray.realp, 1, &scale, complexArray.realp, 1, halfN);
vDSP_vsmul(complexArray.imagp, 1, &scale, complexArray.imagp, 1, halfN);

//convert interleaved to real
float *displayData = malloc(sizeof(float)*n);
vDSP_ztoc(&complexArray, 1, (COMPLEX*)displayData, 2, halfN);    

// print cepstrum to debug window
for (int i=0; i < halfN; i++)
    printf("%f\r\n", displayData[i]);
```

Here are the results of the first several bins:

```
-1.036735
0.807992
-0.030310
0.201064
-0.048442
0.071084
-0.050529
0.108412
-0.037282
0.080372
-0.003775
0.102596
-0.027706
0.044470
0.010319
0.041597
-0.050533
0.012725
-0.003895
-0.016887
-0.010547
```

They do 'settle down' towards zero, but the first few numbers are way larger than I was expecting for an unvoiced section. Does my code look incorrect? I think I followed the article quite closely. Why am I getting such large values in the first few bins for an unvoiced section?

Comment: Without a sample of the input it is hard to tell if the result is expected or not. In order to make sure your code is correct, I suggest you use a synthesized input which you know what it's cepstrum should look like, and compare your expectation to the actual result.

Comment: Isn't the following line in your code some problem? "vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX*)logmag, 2, &complexArray, 1, halfN/2);" Shouldn't you use halfN? As the complex conjugates are ignored by in-place fft in Accelerate framework, maybe you need to have duplicate values in your logmag array to get its length to halfN. I'm not very sure but that is the only thing where I see a possible issue. Please let me know if you got it fixed already.